# Public urls for shared photo-streams?

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, iphone, photo-stream

I cannot find the public urls: not in iCloud.com, not in my iPhone and not in my Aperture (OS X). So where are the public urls for the shared photo-streams?

Answer (score 1):

iPhone: After creating the photostream select the arrow to the right of it (or the people tab if you are running iOS 7) and you will see the link under public website - if you select share link, you can copy it, send in email, tweet, post to fb or send in text/imessage.

All these of course if public is set to on.

Comment: The 'people' tab!  Pulling my hair out looking for that link

Answer (score 1):

And if you're using iPhoto on your Mac (Mavericks specifically) you can find the URL via the Shared/iCloud section of iPhoto by selecting the stream and then selecting the i (info) tab. You can select, copy and paste the stream which I couldn't do under ios7.